# jQuery .append() not working in IE, Safari, and Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, append

So I'm using jQuery's AJAX function to read some XML for me and it's worked just fine. But now I'm trying to manipulate the display property of 4 different dynamically generated divs when mouseup is triggered from option items. The size and x/y of the divs are determined by the XML and are parsed through.

My problem lies in the fact that these divs either aren't being generated or just don't show up in IE, Safari, and Chrome. In Firefox and Opera, they do work. I'm using jQuery's .append() to create the divs and then the .css() function to manipulate them. Looking in Chrome's developer tools, I am seeing that the css property being changed in the script is being overridden by the property in the stylesheet. Any fixes?

Divs created here:

```
    case "dynamic":
     var n = name;
     switch(portion){
      case "stub":
      $('.ticket').append("<div class='stubEditable' id='"+n+"' title='stub'></div>");
      break;
      case "body":
      $('.ticket').append("<div class='bodyEditable' id='"+n+"' title='body'></div>");
      break;
     }
    break;
    case "static":
     var n = name;
     switch(portion){
      case "stub":
      $('.ticket').append("<div class='stubEditable' id='"+n+"' title='stub'></div>");
      break;
      case "body":
      $('.ticket').append("<div class='bodyEditable' id='"+n+"' title='body'></div>");
      break;
     }
    break;
```

Mouseup functions that change the display property:

```
$('#StubTemplates').find('.ddindent').mouseup(function(){
    var tVal = $(this).val();
    var tTitle = $(this).attr('title');
    if(!stubActive){
     $('.stubEditable').css('display', 'none');
     $('#'+tVal).css('display', 'block');
     stubActive = true;
    }else{
     $('.stubEditable').css('display', 'none');
     $('#'+tVal).css('display', 'block');
     stubActive = false;
    }
   });
   $('#StubTemplates').find('#stubTempNone').mouseup(function(){
    $('.stubEditable').css('display', 'none');
   });
   $('#BodyTemplates').find('.ddindent').mouseup(function(){
    var tVal = $(this).val();
    var tTitle = $(this).attr('title');
    if(!bodyActive){
     $('.bodyEditable').css('display', 'none');
     $('#'+tVal).css('display', 'block');
     bodyActive = true;
    }else{
     $('.bodyEditable').css('display', 'none');
     $('#'+tVal).css('display', 'block');
     bodyActive = false;
    }
   });
   $('#BodyTemplates').find('#bodyTempNone').mouseup(function(){
    $('.bodyEditable').css('display', 'none');
   });
```

Comment: Anyway that you can trim that code-snippet down to a bare-bones example of what is causing the problem?  Or at least provide some info about the exact ids/classes that are causing the problem?  Any formatting you can do to clean up that snippet would be useful as well.  Cheers.

Comment: Alright, trimmed it down as far as I can go.

Comment: `$('#'+tVal)` ugh. Has anyone ever heard of `document.getElementById(tval)`? The jQuery hash-appending id-getter is so prevalent on the Web... but it's so slow and kludgy.

Comment: @Delan - I hate the string additions as much as anyone else, but the problem is with Javascript itself. It badly needs a string formatter. There are many solutions out in the market, no doubt, but it needs to be in the language. As far as the jQuery id is concerned, I would love a syntax like: `jQuery({id: tVal})`, or `jQuery({'class': classVar})`. jQ 1.4 already offers MooTools like element creation with objects as parameters - http://www.milesj.me/blog/read/77/Element-Creation-In-JQuery-1.4. Something like this for selectors will be great too.

Comment: @Delan - actually jQuery internally uses document.getElementById when detecting an ID selector, so slow and kludgy isn't super accurate here.

Comment: @Matt - I would cache the result of my selectors in local variables. This means that you create a variable for the result of your selector, and can use it multiple times.

var stubTemplates = $('#StubTemplates');
stubTemplates.find(...) etc

The same with using $(this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can see in dev tools that the style is correctly added to the element, the issue is not so much about JQuery as it is about the cascade of CSS.  Normally, anything added directly to the element like this should get precedence, but there are exceptions.  [CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) can cause some confusing behavior.  Do you have an !important somewhere getting in the way?

Also, since you are hiding and showing with display:block and display:none, make sure you do not have a visibility:hidden in CSS which will override.

Also, any reason why you are not just using [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) or [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?  You could also try removing classes that are getting in the way and setting others using [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), or [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

If all else fails you can always try $('.bodyEditable').css('display', 'none !important');.

I try to avoid !important since it causes so many headaches...but it is in the spec for a reason.

Comment: Not one !important. Both .stubEditable and .bodyEditable are set to display: none.

Comment: Just added a link in my answer to an article about CSS Specificity that might be useful.  I have run up against this kind of thing fairly frequently.  I am by no means a CSS guru...I usually defer to our redsident CSS guy on our team and it almost always comes down to some funky cascade/specificty conflict.  The fact that you can see the style added to the elements rules out JQuery...unless JQuery were malforming the style attribute somehow.

Comment: Bradley, I'm not more than a week new to jQuery, so I'm trying to absorb as much as possible at this point. I'll definitely be using show() and hide() in the future. Furthermore, I tried removeClass() as well as addClass() to no avail. Both will be used as well when possible.

Trying to use !important to override the styles did nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the rule that the dev tool tells you is overriding the element style?

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix the problem. The options in the select menu weren't calling the mouseup, so I used a .change() function on the select menu while using a :selected selector to find what was selected.

Big thanks to Bradley for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

simple solution for this problem for me: add to the div you're appending css `display:block;`. probably any other kind of `display:` might help.